# How to make a custom keybind that runs an applescript file?

Tags: software-recommendation, applescript

No additional questions. I'm fine with installing an additional program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, (Automator -> New -> Service) to paste the code, and then (System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services) to bind the Service to a keyboard shortcut.
2. BetterTouchTool
3. Karabiner